# Jquery File Upload size validation before upload

Tags: php, jquery

I have tried to upload two PDF files or one files in one time. Before upload I want to make it's size validation. But bellow code does not work.

```
$('form').submit(function( e ) {  
    if (($("#e_file")[0].files[0].size+$("#b_file")[0].files[0].size > 8388600) || ($("#e_file")[0].files[0].size> 8388600 && $("#e_file")[0].files[0].size=""))  {                   
        alert("files is  over 8Mb in size!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
});

function get_extension(filename) 
{
    return filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parseInt` function like this:

```
size = parseInt($('#e_file')[0].files[0].size) + parseInt($('#b_file')[0].files[0].size);
```